# Function that cycles through integers until a certain criteria is reached

Tags: r

For example, the function goes from 1 upwards through the integers until `i>19`, then stops
like this:

```
for ( i in 1:infinity)
    if i>19
     stop
 print(i)
```

Comment: What is the exactly the difficulty you are having writing the code? You can edit your post to improve it.

Answer (score 0):

- `1:infinity` doesn't work because R doesn't know what `infinity` means (amusingly enough, `1:Inf` returns "Error in 1:Inf : result would be too long a vector"). `for` loops in R (unlike C) necessarily step through vectors - they're not general-purpose iterators. So you can't do what you want with a `for` loop in R.
- `break`, not `stop`, is the right way to terminate a flow-control loop in R

So a `while()` loop works:

```
i <- 1
while (TRUE) {
    i <- i + 1
    if (i>19) break
}
print(i)
## [1] 20
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether you really need it to go to `Inf` but if not you might want the `Position` function

```
x <- 1:1e6
Position(function(x) x > 19, x)
# [1] 20
```